# Что должен содержать refresh token?

Tags: jwt, authenticationtoken

Пользователь логиниться и ему возвращаются `access token + refresh token`. Первый, вроде, понятно - он хранит роли, мб какой-то статус, юзернейм и все это ужно для разграничения доступа. Но что хранит второй? То же самое, только надолго, либо какой-то id для того чтобы достать юзера из базы и слепить ему новый Acces Token?

Comment: Ну, по сути он существует, как вы и сказали, чтобы выписать юзеру новый Access Token

Comment: Ну хорошо) Я хочу реализовать такой протокол, что мне положить в refresh token?

Comment: 1. Это не протокол
2. Ничего, кладите Refresh Token в базу, где будет указан и пользователь, которому он принадлежит

Comment: В access token и refresh token вы можете хранить любую информацию, нужную вам. При этом помните, что refresh token обновляет не только access token, но и самого себя в процессе запроса. В остальном можно почитать еще статейки [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/533868/) и [тут](https://habr.com/ru/company/Voximplant/blog/323160/).

Comment: получается если я сделаю два практически идентичных токена с разницей лишь во времени жизни и буду использовать данные изъятые из рефреш токена для ре-генерации access токена (без обращения к бд), будет хорошо? или не очень)

Answer (score 1):

Дело вот в чем:
В рефреш токене хранятся данные, необходимые для создания нового токена доступа, но не слишком буквально. В моем случае это получилось так:

1. Создаем токен доступа. Создаем рефреш токен в виде абсолютно случайной строки
2. Берем 6 последних символов с токена доступа и клеим к рефреш токену
3. Токен сохраняем в бд под юзер айди
   Получилось, что они в привязке, и по рефреш токену можно получить юзера из бд